# Как правильно составить запрос к Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица date|sum
В поле date содержится дата формата DATE (2018-01-01)
В поле sum содержится число (например 5000)

Задача: составить запрос на выборку данных таким образом, что бы на выходе получить массив с суммой всех значений sum за один месяц.

Пример:

- 2018-01-01 | 5000
- 2018-01-02 | 3000
- 2018-02-01 | 1000

На выходе должно быть:

- Январь - 8000
- Февраль - 1000

Перечитал кучу манов, форумов, статей, но не нашел решение. Подскажите, как лучше и правильней сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вот так, вроде работает:

```
SELECT SUM(sum_bill), date_format(date_bill, '%d.%m.%Y') as date_bill FROM `bill` GROUP BY MONTH(`date_bill`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select extract(year_month from `date`) month, sum(`sum`) from T
group by extract(year_month from `date`)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
monthname(fullDate) AS month,
SUM(amount) AS totalSales
FROM your_table
GROUP BY monthname(fullDate)
ORDER BY month(fullDate) ASC